# how to create a class in python which would store a tree

Tags: python

I want to make a class in python, which would store a tree.Keeps taking three inputs the main node the left node and right node and stores it in such a way that later I can print it in tree format.

Comment: What have you got so far? Where are you stuck on?

Comment: also, be advised that it is polite to accept 'the best' answer to your questions. Then it won't say '0% accept' in your avatar.

Comment: @Aaron, agreed -- that 0% (and the OP's recent history) just turn me right off.

Comment: Hey sorry guys I was not knowing this procedure :) I thought I dont have to select the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help http://knuth.luther.edu/~pythonworks/Source/chap5/